# Web API ASP.NET Core Post Request 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm new at ASP.NET core and trying to POST a file to a server, but keeps getting 415 Unsupported Media Type error even before hitting any of the code. It does not matter whether the file is PNG, PDF, or even TXT. Is there a setting that I'm missing here? I'm testing it with Postman using POST request and form-data. Thanks in advance for any help I could get.

[image: Postman screenshot]

Here's the Web API side:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImageUploadController : ControllerBase
{
    public static IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public ImageUploadController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public class FileUploadAPI
    {
        public IFormFile files { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> Post(FileUploadAPI objFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (objFile.files.Length > 0)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\");
                }
                using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\" + objFile.files.FileName))
                {
                    objFile.files.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Flush();
                    return "\\Upload\\" + objFile.files.FileName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Failed";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [FromForm] .

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> Post([FromForm]FileUploadAPI objFile)
    {
        // codes
    }
```

Comment: That's it. The devil is in the details. Thanks a lot!